# How to share resources connected by USB on a wireless Network (eg HDD, Flash)

Tags: networking, wireless, external-hdd, sharing

I've got two Ubuntu machines running 14.04 LTS connected over a Wireless network.  I can share folders on the internal HDD on both machines with no problem but when I try to share a resource connected via USB (not a Printer) it seems to become more difficult.  Pretty sure that I am missing something with permissions but now stuck.  I am interested in the HDD and Flash at the moment but the next step could be a Webcam, for example.

Comment: can't you share it via samba?